# ExtJS 4 EditorGrid with Grouping: how to edit multiple rows at once

Tags: javascript, extjs

in ExtJS 4 I have an EditorGrid with Grouping feature. I want to make it possibile to edit multiple rows at once, i.e. write a value for a field once and have it propagated to all rows in the group.

Example: let's have a store in wich records have these fields: id, title. I want to group records by title and change all records that have title=foo with title=bar.

Is it possibile?

I have tried adding some custom javascript to the groupHeaderTpl but every time I click on the header the group toggle collapsing, and anyway I don't think it's a clean solution.

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest implementing it with a grid + form panel, where from grid you select the rows you want to edit and when a field in form is edited, you apply the value to all selected rows.

I've successfully implemented something like this before. It needs a fair amount of work though, as there are bunch of corner cases, but in general it's the simplest solution I can think of.

Comment: It would be good to implement that as a plugin, like RowEditing and CellEditing ones.

Comment: Maybe it could be done as a plugin, but I see it more as a special kind of FormPanel that's able to load not one but a list of records.

Comment: The thing is: if you load multiple records into a FormPanel, you kinda like go away from the FormPanel's concept in the first place. The plugin would be created to allow the selection of multiple records on the grid, and let the FormPanel submit the data to all of them.

Comment: Oh, but you need no plugin for that. Grid already allows multi-selection and just updating all the records will update the rows in grid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything that suits you out-of-the-box exists. You would have to write something like this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: are you working with the concept of [Row Editing](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/grid/row-editing.html)?

Because if so, you are kinda in the wrong direction. The principle of the Row Editing is, like the name says for itself, to allow the user to edit a single row.

If you need a specific feature for editing multiple rows, you are gonna have to, like [@sha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274519/sha) correctly said, implement it by yourself.

To guide you in the possible right direction, both the [CellEditing](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing) and [RowEditing](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing) plugins are based on the same events - `beforeedit()`, `edit()`, `validateedit()` - that get called in different times of the editing action.

You could create your own MultipleRowEditing plugin and use those same events to achieve what you want.